# How to count up starting at any specified number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a number in a div:

```
<div id="value">100</div>
```

And I have this javascript acting on it:

```
function animateValue(id){
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var current = obj.innerHTML;
    setInterval(function(){
        current++;
    },1000);
}

animateValue(value);
```

To my understanding, this script translates to:
• Grab the HTML element called (in this case) "value" and store it in "obj"
• Take the inner html from obj and store it in "current"
• Take the "current" variable and increment it every second

It was supposed to take the content of `#value` and increment it up by one every second, but instead it does nothing. How do I solve this? What have I done wrong? As you can tell, I am not experienced in javascript, so go easy on me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You changed the `current` number but never updated the `innerHTML` of the  `obj`, which is what is actually displayed. If you set `obj.innerHTML = current;` right after `current++` it should do something for you.

And change `animateValue(value);` to `animateValue('value');` (thanks, @nevermind)

Comment: Could you jsfiddle that for me please?

Comment: + change: animateValue(value); to animateValue('value');

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you wanted to update the contents of the DIV. Maybe this is what you wanted?

```
function animateValue(id){
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var current = parseInt(obj.innerHTML);
    setInterval(function(){
        current++;
        // Update the contents of the element
        obj.innerHTML = current;
    },1000);
}

animateValue('value');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L1q5t9gz/

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery. It's easier... The other answers are more complex, this is an easy one.. No parse or something like that.... Simpler code, more effective.

So, It's more simple than you think: First... check the current value, then add and print

```
                $(function(){
                    //Get Current HTML
                    var currentValue = $("#value").html();

                    //do this every 1000 ms (1 second)
                    setInterval(function(){
                        //add the value to the current
                        var newValue = currentValue++
                        // print the new value
                        $("#value").html(newValue);

                    },1000)
                })
```

Comment: This solution is more complex than the others because you need to understand what the DOM is AND you need to know what all that jQuery stuff is about, to do exactly the same thing!

Comment: I like this solution, it works well and as you said it is simple. Though, I did not choose this for two reasons: 1. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I feel like jQuery would create more overhead. 2.This is not the javascript specific answer I was looking for... Still, you get my up vote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the JSFiddle example solving your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/rszczypka/f5jfn5bo/

the html part:

```
<div id="value">100</div>
```

the javascript part:

```
function animateValue(id){
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var current = parseInt(obj.innerHTML);

    setInterval(function(){
        obj.innerHTML = current++;
    },1000);
}

animateValue('value');
```